# How to redirect after changing product URL?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

I'm trying to change products URL on save using:

`$product->setUrlKey($url);`.

It works just fine but when I't trying to reach in front the product, it's responsing to Old URL. 
How can I make product to respond to New Url?

Comment: According to magento takes all config data from cache folder you have to clear the magentodir/var/cache - including all subfolders - to be sure the new config is taken. & even browser cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its showing old url then `core_url_rewrite` table is not updated,  in this case you have to do `reindexing` please do `reindexing` and let me know its working or not

301 url redirect in `.htacess` for you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     redirect 301 baseurl/old_url.html  base_url/new_url.html
</IfModule>
```

Above code is for `.htaccess` file only

Comment: It didn't work. I have product save with one url, and in front it shows old url.

Comment: truncate this table and then do reindexing and then let me know

Comment: Now it works! But when I reach old URL in front it gives me `"Adress dosn't exist"`. How can I make old link redirect automatically to new one?

Comment: Use 301 url redirect rule in magento

Comment: If My answer solve your problem then mark as accepted

Comment: goto `catalog->url rewrite management` and your url there , Or 301 url rewrite in your .htaccess file

Comment: For now I have saved the product new url ald make it works. I don't know how to make frontend url to automaticcaly redirect to new url.

Comment: I've tried to add In catalog-> Urlrewrite but it dosn't work

Comment: Please check my updated answer for `.htaccess`